# Logging as admin and redirect to separate module

Tags: jsp, servlets, web.xml

I want to make separate module for admin if user is admin it should redirect to separate module or pages(that module can only accessible by admin). This task i want to achieve using jsp and servlet or web.xml can anyone help me ....?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make a separate `Admin` module , no need to make another `web.xml`

In your **log-in** page after you submit , handle the request in your servlet

For example,

In Login servlet,

```
if(user_type==admin)

//redirect it to another page , which you have for the admin
```

Hope this helps !

***note : If you need any help . please try something and post here to get your problem solved***

Comment: thanks for your answer i understood it and its working.I have another problem i am working on it which is related to same issue if i will not available to solve that problem i will post again..

Comment: @Saurabh post your question and add its link here . i will try to help you

Comment: here is link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23102913/database-fields-value-saving-everyday